# How get objects in an observable array after a http request in typeScript?

Tags: angular, ionic4

This is my `.ts` :

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

variable = Number();
myObservableArray : Observable<any[]>;

OnClickFunction(){

    this.myObservableArray = this.httpClient.get<any[]>("http://myUrl/?lbs="+this.variable,{responseType: 'json'});

console.log(this.myObservable.Array)
```

I can see the json array in the html but I don't manage to get the objects inside in the .ts!

Comment: typo? `console.log(this.myObservable.Array)` -> `console.log(this.myObservableArray)`. Also, you aren't subscribing to the get function in the `ts`, so if you are seeing it in the 'html', are you using the `async` pipe there?

Comment: Yes I think, this is my html:                                                                                               <ion-item *ngIf="this.mainLeftDec | async as array">
    {{ array| json }}
  </ion-item> and it work, I see all the objects of json. But I don't manage to work with the objects in the .ts

Answer (score 1):

As is, you won't see anything your array in the `console.log`. That is for a few reasons. `this.myObservableArray` is an `Observable` of type `any[]`. At most currently, you will see the Observable wrapper in your console, but not the array. Observables are asynchronous, so the line `this.myObservableArray = this.httpClient...` is setting up the http call to run, but until the `Observable` returned from that method is `subscribe`d to, the http call won't actually occur. The best way to update your code to see the array from the ts file would be as follows:

```js
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {tap} from 'rxjs/operators';

variable = Number();
myObservableArray : Observable<any[]>;

OnClickFunction(){

    this.myObservableArray = this.httpClient.get<any[]>("http://myUrl/?lbs="+this.variable,{responseType: 'json'}).pipe(tap(arr => console.log(arr)));
```

The `| async` (or [AsyncPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe)) will handle subscribing to and unsubscribing from that `Observable`. The operator `tap` will allow you to see the array from the ts file without modifying it at all.